# equivalent of grpc.core.testing for grpc.net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, grpc-c#

I got a test for a grpc client written using c#. In the test there's usage of a call like this:

```
TestCalls.AsyncUnaryCall<MyReply>( ... )
```

This `TestCalls` comes from a nuget of gRPC.Core.Testing. I now need to convert all usage of grpc.core to grpc.net.

Is there an equivalent of this call for grpc.net?

Comment: A version of Grpc.Core.Testing that's grpc-dotnet specific currently doesn't exists, but if you don't mind pulling in the Grpc.Core dependency in your test project, you might be able to use Grpc.Core.Testing with grpc-dotnet as well (AFAIK the Grpc.Core.Testing doesn't use Grpc.Core in any real way, it just has a formal dependency on it).

Comment: @JanTattermusch After asking this question it started to not only be a nuisance, but is also giving me issues. When I try to add a field to the grpc call (a value to the deadline), the tests crash on this TestCalls I've mentioned in the question. I don't know what exactly is wrong there but the only difference is the cahnge from grpc.core to dotnet